# What is the meaning of *modern World*?

Tags: discussion, editing

What is the meaning of ***modern world*** and it's use around Dhamma and Vinaya and in Buddhism. It would be maybe interesting to know the words [folk etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_etymology) and original [etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology), it's "everybodies" notion and its deeper meaning in regard of Dhamma. Maybe also certain other preoccupations in regard of *modern* and *world* and *modern world*.

And could there be traced a word or word combination used for similar purpose, in the ancient texts?

Comment: I moved this to Meta because its subject is clearly the *tag* (what this tag means and what subjects it should be used for); unlike similar questions about *dukkha* and *buddha-nature* which I left on the main site because they're also questions about Buddhist terminology/dharma.

Answer (score 3):

I created the [modern-world](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-world) tag in the early days of the site. I intended it to be used to tag any questions that have something to do with the modern world as we live it now and how practice and the modern world support each other or not as the case may be. Topics that I thought would be under this would be

- technology
- careers
- relationships
- money
- capitalism
- politics generally
- environmental concerns
- things I'd not thought of

I put a tag wiki in to describe which I think is a fair description of what I intended

> Particular issues relating to Buddhism as practiced today. These
>   topics include but are not limited to technological, political and
>   consumer issues that impact on Buddhist thought and practice.

But if anyone (you?) wants to retag the questions, edit the tag-wiki or put in additional tags to sub-categorise it then you should totally do it.

Hope that helps

Comment: One of my favorite tags on the stack, kudos Crab